# Target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting while installing pod in rn firebase

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I am trying to add firebase in my react native app in ios. I have created Podfile with pod init. But when i'm trying to install pod with pod install i'm getting this error.

[image]

Also when i run the app it shows this:

[image]

i have already tried adding $(inherited) in target Build Settings -> Other linker flags. But somehow it's not working.

I'm using :

- React Native "0.58.5"
- React Native Firebase "^5.2.2"

Here is my `Podfile`

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'movit_driver' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for movit_driver

  target 'movit_driverTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'movit_driver-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for movit_driver-tvOS

  target 'movit_driver-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: can you share your Podfile too?

Comment: Did you add it to `$(inherited)` the tvOS target?

Comment: Sorry for the late response @wicky but here's the podfile https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a7xmdb?embed=1&file=index.js

Comment: Yes i did but that's not working @Andrew

Comment: Looking at your podfile I do not see `pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.15.0'` added as per the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios)

Comment: after pod init when i try to run pod 'Firebase/Core' it shows unknown command @wicky

Comment: you don't run that as a command, you paste it into your Podfile and then run `pod install`. I suggest that you read the instructions in the `react-native-firebase` [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios) as you are not following them

Comment: Did that. But still showing the same error after the pod install command. @wicky

Comment: I see you havent had any libraries installed through cocoapods yet. For my personal recommendation, i prefer to not use `cocoapods` whenever possible, because it does too much magic, and sometimes its hard to debug. You can try installing the `react-native-firebase` [manually like how this docs does](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#manual-linking)

Comment: Yes you are right i haven't installed through cocoapods anything yet. But the first image error i shared i think the problem is lying there. I am looking at `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-movit_driver-tvOSTests/Pods-movit_driver-tvOSTests.release.xcconfig'. $(inherited) is already at OTHER_LDFLAGS. The other option is removing build settings from the target. How do i do that?